# How to use nested function in another function as argument in racket language?

Tags: function, functional-programming, nested, racket, nested-function

I would like to create function inside definition:

```
(define example
'(
  (define (func)
   (rectfc 200 0 "blue")
   )
  )
 )
```

and then use it as arguments in another function

```
(execute 400 400 example '(func)))
```

without (eval) function.

Comment: Local definitions are local; you can't access their names from outside their scope. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you ultimately hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for quoting.

```
#lang racket

(define (run-f args)
  (define (add-one n) ; <- defining a function locally
    (+ n 1))          ; 
  (map-f   add-one    ; <- passing into another function
           args))

(define (map-f f args)
  (map f              ; <- using the function that
       args))         ;    was passed in


(run-f '(1 2 3))
; = 2 3 4
```